# limit the drop down link display in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created an dropdown list, it have more than 25 link dropdown to display , So
i need to show only 3 from the dopdown list (not to disable others) , and perform the search option to all . please help me to find a solution

```
 <div class="dropdown">
<input onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn" id="myInput" 
   onkeyup="filterFunction()">
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
<a href="#about">About</a>
<a href="#base">Base</a>
<a href="#blog">Blog</a>
<a href="#contact">Contact</a>
<a href="#custom">Custom</a>
<a href="#support">Support</a>
<a href="#tools">Tools</a>

</div>
</div>

<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function filterFunction() {
var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
input = document.getElementById("myInput");
filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
        a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    }
     }
   </script>
```

> css file

```
     .dropbtn {
        background-color:#E8E0DE;
        color: white;
        padding: 6px;
        font-size: 16px;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
         }

    .dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
     background-color:#FAF6F5;
      }
     #myInput {
      border-box: box-sizing;
      position:relative;
      top: 10px;
      color:black;
      background-position: 1px 2px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      font-size: 16px;
      padding: 5px 350px 10px 15px;
      border: none;
      }

    .dropdown {
     position: relative;
     display: inline-block;
      }

    .dropdown-content {
     display: none;
      position: absolute;
     background-color: #f6f6f6;
    min-width: 230px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
     }

 .dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  }

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd}

 .show {display:block;}


</style>
```

Comment: Could you please add the `CSS` too??

Answer (score 0):

You just want to return at most 3 at all times you'll want to add a function similar to your filter function, but after it finds 3 items that have a display style set to "" set the rest to "none".

```
function limitVisibility() {
let div, a, i;
div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    let counter = 0;
    if (counter < 3 && a[i].style.display === "" ) {
        counter += 1;
    } else {
        a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

and include it in your onClick and onkeyup:

Comment: Brother i need to limit the results to 3 while perform the onclick="myFunction() function

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function filterFunction() {
var input, value, filter, ul, li, a, i, limit, init;
input = document.getElementById("myInput");
value = document.getElementById("myInput").value; // ADD INPUT VALUE
filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
init = 0;
limit = 3;    
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

    if( (a[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1)  ) {
        if (init < limit) // LIMIT to FIRST 3 results
          { 
            a[i].style.display = "";
          }
        else if(value =='') // Case when Input is Empty
         { 
            a[i].style.display = "";
         }
       else
         {
             a[i].style.display = "none";
         }
        init++; // counting results 

    }
   else 
   {
        a[i].style.display = "none";
   }
}
```

}